# Fix MySQL Server data directory

Tags: mysql, windows, server, configuration

I have a very weird Problem on Windows 10 with MySQL Server 8:

I could not start the mysql server or service with 
`mysqld` or `net start mysql` as mysql reported a missing **data** directory (it could not write a 'test file'). It is/was looking in `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0`.

After some googling I could start the mysql server after running
`mysqld --initialize`, which did create a **data** folder beneath `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` and reseted the password somehow. Unfortuneatly, all my databases are gone after I connect to the (I think so) newly initialized mysql server.

After some more googling I found, that there is the following directory on my PC:
`C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` 
... and voilà .. inside that **Data** directory there are folders with names of my (lost) databases. So I am pretty sure, that my data is in there.

But how do I set up the mysql server to use this correct data/settings whatever. I do not want to use a newly initialized mysql server.

I tried copying the folders from `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` to `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` but with no luck. One time the server could not be started, on the other occasion the data was just ignored.
I also tried to copy a my.ini to `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0` and change the datadir entry beneath [mysqld] -> No luck.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE:

The following errors and warnings appear in my ".err" file:

2020-03-11T19:21:10.658537Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010915] [Server] 'NO_ZERO_DATE', 'NO_ZERO_IN_DATE' and 'ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO' sql modes should be used with strict mode. They will be merged with strict mode in a future release.

2020-03-11T19:21:10.659813Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe (mysqld 8.0.19) starting as process 4040

2020-03-11T19:21:11.340219Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.

2020-03-11T19:21:11.358861Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013143] [Server] Column count of mysql.user is wrong. Expected 51, found 49. The table is probably corrupted

2020-03-11T19:21:11.359562Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.db. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.360108Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.360680Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.tables_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.361259Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.columns_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.361881Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.362474Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.procs_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.363076Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.363713Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.364309Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.364908Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.role_edges. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.365505Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.role_edges. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.366123Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.default_roles. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.366774Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.default_roles. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-03-11T19:21:11.367391Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.global_grants. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.368010Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.password_history. The table is probably corrupted!
2020-03-11T19:21:11.369081Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from mysql.global_grants. The table is probably corrupted!

2020-03-11T19:21:11.369779Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.

2020-03-11T19:21:11.371103Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting

2020-03-11T19:21:12.355716Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.19)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.

I tried to run **mysql_upgrade**, which just tells me, that it cannot be run because the upgrade tool is deprecated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve my problem.
For some reason the deprecated upgrade tool was integrated into the server tool.
I had to run

```
mysqld --defaults-file="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/my.ini" --upgrade=FORCE
```

this was not all to the problem. For some other unknown reasons, my password for the root user was not accepted anymore.
Threfore I had to reset my password by this procedure: [Chapter 4 Resetting the Root Password: Windows Systems](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.7/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html)

Summary: Fixing my problem by

1. Using the **--defaults-file** parameter of **mysqld** to point to the correct my.ini file
2. Fixing the path to the correct data dir in the my.ini file
3. running upgrade on server by the parameter **--upgrade=FORCE**
4. resetting the password of my mysql user

I still have no idea, why this desaster happened, anyway....

Comment: I don't think that is a mysql problem, chekck your harddrive with smart if there are more problems. also check the event log of windows, there should be some errors

Answer (score 1):

One folder above the data dir is a my.ini file, there is the main configuration file of mysql.

Mysql finds this file by starting the service with

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" MySQL80
```

See if you have this option correctly

```
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data
```

Comment: Thank you, for your help. Unfortunatly, this did not solve my problem. But maybe I am a step further. With the --defaults-file flag I was able to produce some Error messages in the .err file, pls. see the updated section in my question

Answer (score 0):

Add mysqld to the System path variable.
The path generally looks like "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin"

First, install the windows service as MySQL80.
Open cmd as Administrator and use.

**mysqld --install MySQL80 --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini"**

**Note**: --defaults-file will be your MySQL ini file

Issue following command to start the service

**sc start MySQL80**

Use the following command, if you want to start mysqld manually

**mysqld --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console**

**Note**: --console will output the mysqld log. Check the [Error] blocks and fix errors accordingly.

**Reference**: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-service.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue because the default C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini file had a typo in it.

In the file as created by installer v1.6:

```
datadir=C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0\Data
```

Issue: no quotes on a filepath with spaces, and they mixed up the forward and backslashes. The slashes may not be relevant as it's Windows, but the lack of quotes definitely is. I fixed both anyway.

Fix:
Overwrite that line with:

```
datadir="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 8.0/Data"
```