# mysql 8.0 errors - how to run mysql_upgrade

Tags: mysql

on my dev machine (Ubuntu 20.04, mysql-server 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) my laptop needed to be turned off, and since that mysql does not start.

I've table corruption errors like this:

```
2022-07-01T12:13:08.666633Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013139] [Server] Cannot load from 
mysql.proxies_priv. The table is probably corrupted!
2022-07-01T12:13:08.666748Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010316] [Server] Fatal error: Could not 
read the column 'authentication_string' from table 'mysql.user'. Please perform the 
MySQL upgrade procedure.
2022-07-01T12:13:08.666825Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010952] [Server] The privilege system 
failed to initialize correctly. For complete instructions on how to upgrade MySQL to 
a new version please see the 'Upgrading MySQL' section from the MySQL manual.
2022-07-01T12:13:08.667187Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
```

I'd be happy to run mysql_upgrade, however:

```
The mysql_upgrade client is now deprecated. The actions executed by the upgrade client are now done by the server.
To upgrade, please start the new MySQL binary with the older data directory. Repairing user tables is done automatically. Restart is not required after upgrade.
The upgrade process automatically starts on running a new MySQL binary with an older data directory. To avoid accidental upgrades, please use the --upgrade=NONE option with the MySQL binary. The option --upgrade=FORCE is also provided to run the server upgrade sequence on demand.
It may be possible that the server upgrade fails due to a number of reasons. In that case, the upgrade sequence will run again during the next MySQL server start. If the server upgrade fails repeatedly, the server can be started with the --upgrade=MINIMAL option to start the server without executing the upgrade sequence, thus allowing users to manually rectify the problem.
```

It seems mysql_upgrade is not supported at this version. What can I do to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/mysql-8-0-16-mysql_upgrade-is-going-away/ says:

> From MySQL 8.0.16 onwards:
>
> 1. Shutdown the server and install the new binaries
> 2. Start the server and let the server upgrade the data dictionary tables and system tables.

Read the article I linked to for more details.

You may have to force the MySQL Server to apply the upgrades to tables, by using `mysqld --upgrade=FORCE` as mentioned in the article. Another user reports having to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60643682/20860).